# How do I use file names in a sed command?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

I have a number of `.conf` files that are identical and in the same directory, with the exception of having different file names. In each uniquely named `.conf` file, I would like to replace a set of characters in the file with the name of the file. For example:

Currently in all files:

```
datafname = example.nex
ofprefix = best.example
```

Ideal output:

Filename: `25.conf`

```
datafname = 25.nex
ofprefix = best.25
```

Filename: `26.conf`

```
datafname = 26.nex
ofprefix = best.26
```

I thought that I could use `sed` to run through all these files to find and replace the string of text with the file name using something like:

```
sed -i conf 's/example/echo $f/g' *
```

but this is not working properly. Would anyone happen to have a suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do:

```
for f in *.conf; do
    base=$(basename "$f" '.conf') # gives '25' from '25.conf'
    sed -i.before "s/example/$base/g" "$f"
done
```

When using the `-i` switch to `sed`, you must be absolutely sure that your `sed` command works because `-i` changes the files *in-place*. This means the generated output will overwrite the input file. If your replacement command (`s/…/…/`) is wrong, you may end up with empty files and no backups. Hence, I used `-i.before` which will leave a `*.before` file with the original content.

Comment: Yes, this is 100% on topic @foolsparadise. PerlDuck, please familiarize yourself with the site's scope before suggesting otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a for loop to iterate over the files. Use parameter expansion to remove the file extension. Use double quotes around the expression, otherwise the variable wouldn't be expanded.

```
#! /bin/bash
for f in *.conf ; do
    b=${f%.conf}
    sed -i "s/example/$b/" "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the task without a loop using GNU `parallel` [image: Install parallel]:

```
parallel sed -i.old s/example/{.}/ {} ::: *.conf
```

This is especially useful if you have a *lot* of files to edit, as `parallel` runs one job per CPU core.

- `-i.old` means: edit the file `i`n-place and make a backup adding the `.old` extension to the original filename (remove `.old` if you don't want a backup, but remember you don't have a backup then)
- `s/example/{.}/g` means `s`ubstitute `example` with the input filename without its extension (`{.}`) and do it `g`lobally (= to every occurence)
- `{}` is replaced with the input filename
- `:::` separates the command to run from the arguments to pass to it
- `*.conf` matches every `.conf` file in the current directory

Comment: @OleTange You're probably right, I'm not quite sure about the correct terminology and just described the feature like in `man parallel` now. Thank you!

Comment: Elegant solution. Initially I worried whether it would break if the filenames contain space, but you got that covered, too.

Comment: @OleTange I? No, `parallel` covered it! It's just an amazing piece of software if you ask me, useful as a replacement to almost every `for` loop and `xargs` call.

Comment: @OleTange Oh wait, I just realized you may have already known that. :D Thank you very much for making things so easy, `--will-cite`!

Answer (score 1):

With awk, which has a `FILENAME` variable automatically set to the filename (and, if GNU awk, with edits in-place as well):

```
$ for i in {20..26}; do printf "%s\n" "datafname = example.nex" "ofprefix = best.example" > $i.conf; done
$ gawk -i inplace 'FNR == 1 {split(FILENAME, file, ".")} {gsub("example", file[1])} 1' *.conf
$ cat 25.conf
datafname = 25.nex
ofprefix = best.25
```

- `FNR == 1 {split(FILENAME, file, ".")}`: on the first line of each file, split the filename on `.` and store it in the `file` array
- `{gsub("example", file[1])} 1`: for all lines, replace `example` with the first element of the `file` array and print.